# What's the most efficient way to export all layers of a Paint.NET .pdn file to separate images?

Tags: export, paint.net

I have a .pdn file with 82 layers. I want to export all of these to separate files (with the end goal being to make a video file slide show). What is the most efficient way to do this?

I started down the path of using the "ZIP Archive" file type plugin, but Chrome bounced that download - it looks like it matches the signature of some trojans (https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/31996-zip-archive-filetype-plugin-zip/). Given this, I am not interested in this specific plugin.

Answer (score 0):

At first save your PDN image in Photoshop format (=PSD). Here's a plugin which claims to do it:  https://www.psdplugin.com The plugin is working and available, but I have tried it only with a few layers, no idea what happens with tens of layers.

Open the PSD file in Photoshop or in some other program which supports PSDs and can export layers as separate files. One free option is web service Photopea. Again: No idea how well Photopea works with tens of layers, I have had only a few.

GIMP can also be used. It opens Photoshop PSDs and there's a plugin which separates layers to files https://khalim19.github.io/gimp-plugin-export-layers/ I have never tried this plugin.

**Warning:** GIMP allows different layer sizes. Imported PSDs have cropped layers if there's transparent areas at the edges. Make the layers to cover full image size before exporting the layers if you are going to align some of the exported layers properly later.