# Convert multi-layer Paint.NET (pdn) files to Krit (kra)

Tags: layers, krita

I am moving to a Mac from Windows and [thus moving away from Paint.NET](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/19254-best-paintnet-alternative-for-mac/).

I have several multi-layer Paint.NET (.pdn) files that I would like to continue using.  How can I move these easily to Krita?

I know I could save each layer as a separate image and create a new Krita project and add each layer one by one.  I would prefer a single multi-layer export and import or something simple like that.

I have one solution that I have discovered that I will post as an answer, but welcome any better answers!

Comment: I don't understand: 3 downvotes and no comments. Would the downvoters please indicate what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - it has absolutely nothing to do with photography. [I didn't dv, but vtc]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using an image editing program without any obvious connection to photography.

Comment: @Tetsujin Paint.NET and Krita are free photo editing software.  I chose this forum because they are mentioned here.  If another Forum is better than this one can you please recommend?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Suspicion of spam.

Comment: tbh, I'm not comfortable with the heavy down-voting, even if I don't think it's on-topic.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the StackExchange community and trying my best to follow all the rules.  This is not spam.  I was frustrated that the answer to my question was spread over three different websites and thought I would participate in a community that may appreciate my research.  Sorry if I landed in the wrong one.  Maybe the graphic design community would have been better.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question (it lacks research), so a downvote is fine, but a comment noting why it's downvoted is the least you can do for a new user. And this is about using a photo editor right? We have a bunch of them [on photoshop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop), so I don't see why this question would not fit (besides the lack of research). Regarding the spam: what signals trigger that suspicion?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, the question is about images, multiplayer, not photos....

Comment: @RomeoNinov An photo is an image, right? If I would use Paint.NET as my multi-layer photo editor and would like to move to a Mac, then this question would be very relevant to me such that I can continue using free tools to edit my photos.
If you look at the "Related" section of this question, you'll see plenty of upvoted questions that are about using an image editor (to edit a photograph).

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Photgraphy is not the same thing as general image editing. This is better here but only marginally

Answer (score 1):

Big picture answer: Export from Paint.NET in the ORA format then import into Krita

https://www.reddit.com/r/krita/comments/flwbwg/how_to_open_pdn_in_krita/

1. Download the [OpenRaster (ORA) plugin for Paint.NET](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/20984-openraster-filetype/)
2. Install the plugin.  To do this save the DLL file you just downloaded to the FileTypes folder in Paint.NET (follow [these steps](https://boltbait.com/pdn/InstallingEffects.php) for details, but use FileTypes not the Effects folder)
3. Open the .pdn file you wish to export in Paint.NET and choose File->Save as.  Then choose OpenRaster (*.ora) as the file type.
4. Open the .ora file with Krita.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/137804) you can use PSD format as intermediate.

You did (almost) zero research about the possibilities.